# Maple and Wolfram Alpha showing different answers for simple calculation

Tags: maple, wolfram-alpha

I put this into Maple

$Y(a, y):= 2^a-2^a*y((1-y)^2)-\sqrt(1/2^a) $

$Y(0.5, 1/2);
                         -0.1337896344$

and this into Wolfram Alpha

$2^{1/2}-2^{1/2}*(1/2)((1-(1/2))^2)-\sqrt(1/2^{1/2}))=0.37$

How is this possible??

[image]

Comment: Indeed the answer is different than these two: $$-\frac{1}{4
   \sqrt{2}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt[4]
   {2}}+\sqrt{2}\approx 0.39654$$

Comment: @Masacroso yea it was 0.39 but it wanst negative atleast

Comment: @Masacroso the same as in 0.39?

Comment: You should show the syntax that you used in both.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I added screenshot

Comment: You dont need double parenthesis in the maple code or surround the $a$ inside the square root by parenthesis, and you need to separate the $y$, with a space, from the parenthesis.

Comment: @Masacroso there we go! Add to answer if you wanna get some pts.

Comment: @Masacroso: but what is Maple's interpretation then ?

Comment: @Yves Idk... but some time ago I get a similar error because I dont separates the symbols correctly. I think that maple is interpreting $y(...$ as a function or so (not sure).

Comment: @Masacroso: I would assume so, but shouldn't it complain that the function $y$ is undefined or conflicting with the dummy argument ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As is pointed out in the comments, the problem with the Maple code is that the y(...) term is using y as a [function](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=function) application.

When you evaluate your code, you get y(...) = 0.5(...). In Maple, for the case that you have an expression such as 0.5(x), it represents the constant function 0.5 (the function that is 0.5 everywhere); the result of evaluating it is the number 0.5. This would account for the differing result.

The valid Maple code that you should input is:

```
Y := (a,y) -> 2^a - 2^a*y*((1-y)^2)-sqrt(1/2^a);
Y(0.5,0.5);
```

returns:

```
.3965404516
```

Also, note the slight difference in the function declaration in the code above.